# Is there a way to get C99 array designators or alternative in Rust?

Tags: arrays, c, rust, initialization, mapping

I've just completed [a CodeWars kata on vowel-counting](https://www.codewars.com/kata/54ff3102c1bad923760001f3) in C & Rust. The sample code is easy & obvious. Arrays can be used as fast mappings. Here, I map characters to logical values (0 or 1).

**C implementation:**

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// :) This const array design looks smart & IMO-readable. Use of C99 feature.
const uint8_t areVowels[256]= {['a']=1, ['e']=1, ['i']=1, ['o']=1,  ['u']=1};

size_t get_count(const unsigned char *s)
{
  auto size_t count= 0;
  for (;*s!='\0';s++){
    count+= areVowels[*s];
  }
  return count;
}
```

**Rust implementation:**

```
// :( Here is me pain. Unreadable, python3-generated array content.
const ARE_VOWELS:[u8;256]= [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

fn get_count(s: &str) -> usize {
  let mut vowels_count: usize = 0;

  for c in s.bytes(){
      vowels_count+= ARE_VOWELS[c as usize] as usize;
  }
  
  return vowels_count;
}
```

I wish I knew an alternative for array designators in Rust, which are a useful C99 feature. Initialization of the same byte array is much more awkward in my Rust code.

Comment: Ian answer is good. But this solution to the problem is not rusty, imo.

Answer (score 10):

`static mut` is unnecessary here (and also bad practice). You can assign the value of a constant to the value of a code block which is capable of being evaluated in a `const` context

```rs
const ARE_VOWELS: [u8;256] = {
    let mut data = [0u8; 256];
    data['a' as usize] = 1;
    data['e' as usize] = 1;
    data['i' as usize] = 1;
    data['o' as usize] = 1;
    data['u' as usize] = 1;
    data
};
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72340151/5619133) for prettying this up with a macro.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative is a macro that provides the syntax you want, its actually not too hard to make a general purpose implementation:

```rust
macro_rules! array {
    ($def:expr; $len:expr; $([$idx:expr]=$val:expr),* $(,)?) => { {
        let mut a = [$def; $len];
        $(a[$idx] = $val;)*
        a
    } }
}
```

```rust
let data = array![0; 256; ['a' as usize]=1, ['e' as usize]=1];
```

You can of course move the `as usize` into the macro if you like.

Comment: Oh hey look, there's a crate that does this and more: [array-lit](https://docs.rs/array-lit/latest/array_lit/)

Comment: I really like that macro. It's easy & readable, and I've just rewritten it in my way.

Answer (score 0):

I found some (unsafe ⇒ amusing) work around with "mut static value runtime initialization".

```
const VOWELS:&[u8;5]= b"aeiou";
static mut ARE_VOWELS:[u8;256]= [0;256];

fn init(){
    unsafe{
        let ptr: *mut u8= &mut ARE_VOWELS[0];
        for b in VOWELS{
            *(ptr.offset(*b as isize))= 1;
        }
    }
}

fn get_count(s: &str) -> usize {
    init();
    
    let mut vowels_count: usize = 0;

    for c in s.bytes(){
        unsafe{
            vowels_count+= ARE_VOWELS[c as usize] as usize;
        }
    }
  
    return vowels_count;
}
```

**Although** I have serious doubts about the performance & maintainability of such piece of code.