# Rust: is there something like C99 designated range initializer for arrays?

Tags: arrays, rust, constants

The similar question is asked in [Is there a way to get C99 array designators or alternative in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72339950/), but the answers there cannot initialize a value for a give **range**.

For example,

```c
int a[10] = { [4 ... 8] = 10 };
```

How do const arrays in Rust use an initializer on the range? If we don't use `const`, it can be done by `fill()` method:

```rust
let mut a: [i32; 10] = [0; 10];
a[4..9].fill(10);
```

But `fill()` cannot be used in `const` block.

Comment: Not that I know of. You'll have to do it [manually](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4b7dd1872c2d009701d827e08ffa67fb)

Comment: @PitaJ it can be very tedious if there are several ranges. I think maybe macros can simplify it. But I am new to macros.

Comment: with a const fonction you can do loop and do this easy

Comment: Yeah, you can [extract it into a const function](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=76813b10d24759ca542fccd9a598d7c7)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this, but it's possible to create it yourself with a macro:

```rust
macro_rules! array_ranged_init {
    ( $default_value:expr $(, $($min:literal)? .. $($max:literal)? = $value:expr)* ; $len:expr ) => {
        {
            let mut array = [$default_value; $len];
            $(
                #[allow(unused_variables)]
                let min = 0;
                $(let min = $min;)?
                
                #[allow(unused_variables)]
                let max = $len;
                $(let max = $max;)?
                
                let mut i = min;
                while i < max {
                    array[i] = $value;
                    i += 1;
                }
            )*
            array
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use the macro like this:

```rust
static DATA: [i32; 10] = array_ranged_init![0, 4..9 = 10; 10];

#[test]
fn test() {
    assert_eq!(DATA, [0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 0])
}
```

This macro allows you to include multiple ranges:

```rust
static DATA: [i32; 12] = array_ranged_init![
    0,
    1..6 = 4,
    10.. = 6,
    ..1 = 1;
    12
];

#[test]
fn test() {
    assert_eq!(DATA, [1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 6])
}
```

Comment: That's cool! How do modify it so that both range and single index designators are supported. For example, `array_ranged_init![0, 1..6 = 4, 6=5; 10]`.

Comment: It's possible but not trivial. It turns out to be very difficult, with this syntax, to detect the presence or absence of the `..` range adapter in a useful way, so you'd need to totally redesign it to operate recursively.